# React upgrade from 16 to 17

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying React upgrade from 16 to 17. What I should take care of? I have a lot of packages installed. how to handle versions of existing packages, eslint, redux, and other things?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. 

Then [read the release notes](https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html)

Comment: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/10/20/react-v17.html

Answer (score 10):

Update:
React Scripts, react, react-dom.

```
npm install react-scripts@4.0.0 react@17.0.0 react-dom@17.0.0
```

Remove node_modules, package-lock.

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
```

Reinstall and re-build:

```
npm install
npm run build
```

Other libraries:

You may need to upgrade other libraries too.

If you are using Typescript:

```
npm install -D @types/react@17.0.0 @types/react-dom@17.0.0
```

If you are using React Testing Library, you would want to be under 12.1.5, which is the latest version that supports React < 18.00

```
npm install @testing-library/react@"<=12.1.5"
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: You are welcome! If it fixed your problem, would you mind marking it as the accepted answer? Thanks.